# Password compare, why isn't it working?

Tags: php

I am using this to compare the password entered and the confirm password. No matter what, it creates the user. Why so?

here's the database code -

```
$connect = @mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password) or die ('error');
$select = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect) or die('check');
$username=stripslashes(trim($_POST['username']));
$select_record="select * from users where username=' ".$username."' ";
$select_query=mysql_query($select_record)  or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($select_query)==0)

{
    $fullname = stripslashes(trim($_POST['fullname']));
    $email = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $website = stripslashes(trim($_POST['website']));
    $username = stripslashes(trim($_POST['username']));
    $password = stripslashes(trim($_POST['password']));
    $add_new="insert into users (fullname,email,website,username,password) values ('$fullname','$email','$website','$username','$password')";
    $add_query=mysql_query($add_new) or die(mysql_error());
    if($add_query)
    {
        echo "Awesome! You are now a member";
    }
}
else
echo "Please try again";
?>
```

Above connect, i have my database username and password.

Just to revise, here's my current code -

```
<div id="form"><form action="registersuccess.php" method="post">
Full Name<br />
<input type="text" name="fullname"/>
<br /><br />
Website<br />
<input type="text" name="site"/><br /><br />
Email<br />
<input type="text" name="email"/><br /><br />
Username<br />
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="username"/><br />
<br />
Password<br />
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<br />
Confirm Password<br />
<input type="password" name="confirmpass"/><br />
<br />
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Create my Account"/></p>

</form>

<?php
$pass = $_POST['password']; 
$cpass = $_POST['confirmpass'];
$cmp = strcmp($pass, $cpass);

if ($cmp != 0)
{
    echo "check password";
}
else
{
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that you can only accept one answer per question. So as @zengr says, choose which is the best.

Comment: Is your password check code in a function or an include file? Could you show us the database insert code as well? There may be a problem there too.

Comment: Hmmm... how are you checking the passwords? Also, voting up to counter what appear to be meaningless downvotes.

Comment: by using the method you provided. By getting it from post??? I am also getting an undefined index password n confirmpass...i know its getting complicated...but plz try n help me.

Comment: i just revised my post...do check.

Comment: Yes but is this a function, or some include file, and how are you calling the check from/before your database code? Or is this all in the same PHP file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A number of glaring syntax gotchas here. It appears that you're not even seeing any notices/warnings (about undefined variables, undefined constants, etc), so you'd better edit `php.ini` to turn on error reporting (of at least `E_NOTICE` or so), or tack this in the beginning of your scripts:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That'll make syntax "errors" (meaning they're not actual parse errors, but are still typing mistakes that are recognized by PHP to mean something else) much, much easier to catch, as PHP will print messages that tell you if there's anything fishy with your code, and at which files/lines.

Now on to the actual issues with your code.

---

You need to assign the result of `strcmp()` to a variable then check that variable. Also, you can change the if condition to say `$cmp != 0` since you're testing for any kind of inequality, that is, you're testing for `is not 0`.

```
$cmp = strcmp($pass, $cpass);

if ($cmp != 0)
...
```

In fact, by doing that you can completely bypass having to use a temporary variable, and just pass the result of the function call into the condition statement:

```
if (strcmp($pass, $cpass) != 0)
```

Or by directly comparing the strings instead of comparing the `strcmp()` result:

```
if ($pass != $cpass)
```

---

Additionally, as others point out, you got your `POST` value assignments wrong, they should be the other way around, otherwise you're overwriting `$_POST`'s values with nothing. You can also drop the parentheses `( )` for array keys as they're not necessary at all:

```
$pass = $_POST['password']; 
$cpass = $_POST['confirmpass'];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `strcmp`, you need to process the return value of it somehow, either store it temporarily in a variable, for example:

```
$cmpResult = strcmp($pass, $cpass);
if ($cmpResult > 0 || $cmpResult < 0) {
    // …
}
```

Or you use the returned value directly and compare it to `0`:

```
if (strcmp($pass, $cpass) !== 0) {
    echo "password check";
}
```

But you can also compare the variable values directly:

```
if ($pass !== $cpass) {
    echo "password check";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Password<br />
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<br />
Confirm Password<br />
<input type="password" name="confirmpass"/><br />
<br />
<?php
  $pass = $_POST['password']; // previously you assigned undefined variable to $_POST element. Also no need for () when accessing array element
  $cpass = $_POST[('confirmpass')]; 
  $compare = strcmp($pass, $cpass);  //previously function return value wasn't assigned to any variable

 if ($compare !== 0) //some optimization
   {
     echo "password check";
   }
 else
 {
   return true;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST[('password')] = $pass; 
$_POST[('confirmpass')] = $cpass;
```

shouldn't it be tho other way around?

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$cpass= $_POST['confirmpass'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking on the same page as the form? If so, `$_POST` isn't set, and therefore `$pass = $cpass = ''`

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I could see:

You need to get value from the `$_POST` array not assign value to it.
Also you don't really need parenthesis while accessing array element(although its *not* an error to use it.), so to get the value for the key `'foo'` in an array `$arr` you can use `$arr['foo']`.

So you need:

```
$pass = $_POST['password']; 
$cpass = $_POST['confirmpass'];
```

Next you compare the two string using `strcmp` function that return `0` if the two strings are equal and returns non-zero if the differ. So you can do:

```
if( strcmp($pass, $cpass) !== 0) {
  // passwords differ
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you actually assign your values to the posted data instead of the other way around. Please take some time learning the basics before asking these kind of questions.

ie. $pass = $_POST['pass']; etc.